# xcode can iphone sdk be installed to the xcode dev tools

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am very new to iphone dev, rather i just set up a mac. it had OS X 10.6 so i downloaded the latest xcode but it said that i needed a newer OS i.e 10.6.4 . So for the ime being i thought i would use the older version and downloaded the xcode 3.1.4 but being new , i did not know that i was downloading developer tools that was something else. Now in the iphone dev tab in the xcode, there is a link "Download free iphone SDK" but as i click on it , i am taken to the apple website where they want me to join one of their developer programs. Is there some other way i can get my xcode to get an older sdk because i want the older sdk which was probably free and the newer one wont even work for me?

Regards,

Khizar

Comment: What is so difficult about updating OS X 10.6.0 to 10.6.4?

Comment: i will in a day or two , internet is a bit sketchy right now, so i was trying to avoid very big downloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sign into developer.apple.com member center with your Apple ID you should have the option to download xcode3 for snow leopard without paying the developer fee(click programs and add-ons at the top).  I am unable to confirm this because I have paid the fee.

I would highly recommend upgrading to lion and getting xcode 4 though, the transition between the two seemed like a lot and was very annoying (I switched when I was a beginner).  It would save you a lot of time and frustration to start out with xcode 4 in my opinion.

Comment: ya but it will still be the full download with xcode and sdk that is about 3 to 4 Gbs and i am not in a position right now to download so much data. sketchy internet connection , so i was hoping that the link would work and just download the sdk but i guess i will have to wait a day or two to start my development. thanx still :)

Comment: I did go there and was about to download it  (its just as u said) but then i remembered that i already have xcode 3.2.4 which was not working in the first place. So i did not download it.